Connection Issues with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.33 and WebSphere JMS
2024-05-21 15:40:38,522 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection] Errors occurred during the buffering operation
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Transaction not started, XID:[1463898948,globalId=001ffffff8f60ffffffd4ffffffeb4f0002834b37448ffffffa6ffffffc07efffffffe75ffffffa6773a7922ffffffebffffffa9fffffff274ffffff97ffffffe149ffffffebffffffbb,branchId=001ffffff8f60ffffffd4ffffffeb4f0002834b37448ffffffa6ffffffc07efffffffe75ffffffa6773a7922ffffffebffffffa9fffffff274ffffff97ffffffe149ffffffebffffffbb000100000000000002]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection$CommandProcessor.processCommit(OpenWireConnection.java:1549) ~[artemis-openwire-protocol-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection$CommandProcessor.processCommitTransactionTwoPhase(OpenWireConnection.java:1602) ~[artemis-openwire-protocol-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.TransactionInfo.visit(TransactionInfo.java:102) ~[activemq-client-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection.act(OpenWireConnection.java:366) ~[artemis-openwire-protocol-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ThresholdActor.doTask(ThresholdActor.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:57) ~[artemis-commons-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:32) ~[artemis-commons-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.33.0.jar:2.33.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]

I am running Artemis version 2.33, which was previously working fine. I have connected Artemis to WebSphere using JMS and a resource adapter.
After one deployment, I had to restart the application and then restart the MQ. Since then, I have been frequently getting the above error.
Resource adapter configuration:
failover:(tcp://pro-t24-qve-03:61616,tcp://pro-t24-qve-04:61616)?jms.useAsyncSend=true&jms.alwaysSessionAsync=false&jms.optimizeAcknowledge=true

JMS configuration:
External initial context factory:
org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

Resource Adapter Configuration:
failover:(tcp://pro-t24-qve-03:61616,tcp://pro-t24-qve-04:61616)?jms.useAsyncSend=true&jms.alwaysSessionAsync=false&jms.optimizeAcknowledge=true

enter image description here

The stack trace from the broker indicates that the remove client is attempting to commit an XA transaction that hasn't yet been started.

Is there a specific reason you are using org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory from the OpenWire JMS client from ActiveMQ Classic rather than org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory from the Core JMS client from ActiveMQ Artemis?

Because Using the classpath in the websphere
D:\ActiveMQ-Libs\activemq-client-5.16.0.jar
D:\ActiveMQ-Libs\hawtbuf-1.11.jar
D:\ActiveMQ-Libs\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
in WebSphere, and deployed in Resource Adapters > ActiveMQ JMS Resource Adapter with activemq-rar-5.14.5.rar.

What do you mean when you say, "I am running Artemis version 2.33, which was previously working fine"? Were you integrating with WebSphere previously without problems?

This is working fine only and I didn't change any configuration at the MQ level. Two days ago, I restarted the queue, and suddenly I started getting the WARN message frequently in the MQ console. Despite this, the application is working, and messages are processing.
Is there any specific reason for this?

From what I can tell the broker is simply responding to what the client is doing and, as noted previously, the client is attempting to commit an XA transaction that hasn't yet been started. At this point I don't think there's anything the broker can do about this.

We're experiencing an issue with long transactions in WebSphere, where the transaction keeps retrying, resulting in the error mentioned above in the Artemis ActiveMQ. This occurs because the WebSphere application is connected to Artemis ActiveMQ.
When we restart, clearing the transaction log folder in WebSphere resolves the existing transactions, and the error no longer appears in the Artemis console.
